# Confusion in the application of maximum modulus principle

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $ f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C} ,$ entire and $|f(z)|\le \log|z|,\ |z|>1. $

Show that $f$ is constant.

here is the answer I am reading.

> Pick $\epsilon>0$ and let $r=\exp(\epsilon)>1$. Then
>   $|f(z)|\le\epsilon$ for all $z$ with $|z|=r$ by hypothesis. By the
>   maximum modulus principle, $|f(z)|\le \epsilon$ for all $z$ with
>   $|z|<r$, especially for all $z\in\mathbb D$ . Since $\epsilon$ was
>   arbitrary, $f|_{\mathbb D}=0$, hence $f=0$.

I am not able to see how maximum modulus principle is used here? Can someone please explain.

I know the following version of maximum modulus principle

> The absolute value of a nonconstant analytic function on a connected
>   open set G ⊂ C cannot have a local maximum point in G

Comment: Apply your version of MMP to $G = \{|z| < r\}$. There must be a maximum on $\overline{G} = \{|z| \le r\}$ since continuous functions achieve a maximum on compact sets.

Answer (score 0):

A consequence of the  maximum modulus principle is (in the above situation):

for $|z|<r$ we have $|f(z)| \le \max \{|f(w)|:|w|=r\}.$

Hence $|f(z)| \le \epsilon$ for $|z|<r.$

Comment: I don't think this is an explanation of "how the maximum modulus principle is used here".